# How to use visibilitychange event on Firefox Extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm trying to learn how to make a Firefox extension.  I want to create a toolbar that only shows up on a specific page.  I can make the toolbar appear, but then it should become hidden when I open or switch to a new tab, or close the tab with that specific page.  I don't understand how to make the `visibilitychange` event work though, no matter what I try nothing happens.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
  window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
  myExtension.init();  
},false);


var myExtension = {

  init: function (aEvent) {
    gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.showToolbar, false);
  },

  showToolbar: function(aEvent) {
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;

    if(doc.location.href=="http://www.google.ca/"){
      eToolbar=document.getElementById("nav-toolbar");
      eToolbar.hidden=false;

      //no matter how I change this line below it never does anything
      gBrowser.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", this.toggleToolbar, false);
    }
  },

  toggleToolbar: function(aEvent) {
    eToolbar=document.getElementById("nav-toolbar");
    if(document["mozVisibilityState"]=="mozHidden"){
        eToolbar.hidden=true;
    } else {
        eToolbar.hidden=false;
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mozVisibilityState` can be either `visible` or `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired effect by using TabSelect event instead.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
   window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
   myExtension.init();  
},false);


var myExtension = {

   init: function (aEvent) {
      gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.showToolbar, false);
   },

   showToolbar: function(aEvent) {
      var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;

      if(doc.location.href=="http://www.google.ca/"){
         eToolbar=document.getElementById("nav-toolbar");
         eToolbar.hidden=false;

         var container = gBrowser.tabContainer;
         container.addEventListener("TabSelect", myExtension.toggleToolbar, false);
      }
   },

   toggleToolbar: function(aEvent) {
      eToolbar=document.getElementById("nav-toolbar");
      if(window._content.document.location.href=="http://www.google.ca/"){
         eToolbar.hidden=false;
      } else {
         eToolbar.hidden=true;
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I think `TabSelect` will not catch the user typing the target address, or following a link to it.

`pageshow` looks more promising.